# Java array sort descending and print their element number

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

What I am trying to do is sort an array in descending order like this

```
Arrays.sort(array);
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array));
```

and then print which array element was first and then second and then thrird etc..

INPUT:
10 43 77 23
the descending order of them is:
77 43 23 10
I want it to print:
3 2 4 1

If you have any questions feel free to ask me.

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: question 1: what have you tried so far? at this point, wed don't even know what the type of the elements is you are trying to sort. how on earth do you assume we can help you with such little information?

Comment: You will probably need to implement your own sorting algorithm rather than relying on Arrays.sort() and then as you sort each element do a System.out.print(elementIndex + " ")

Comment: Yes sorry, this is my first question here. So I tried save their order in another array but I could find a way to do it right.

Comment: There are many ways actually with the existing question, and all seems to be equivalent, if there is no more constraint, so it is hard to say what is the best option for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with a `Map` with the element as the key, and the index as the value. You'd first have to create this map with a for loop

```
Map<Integer, Integer> indexLookUp = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    map.put(array[i], i);
}
```

Then you can sort the array:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

You don't need the reversing part, as you can just iterate the array backwards. And then print out the index for the element via the map lookup:

```
for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("Element: " + array[i] + ", previous index: " + map.get(array[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you want to print the index of the element in the original array? First you'll need to copy the array, sort the copy and then find the indices in of the sorted elements in the original array. Following code does that.

```
int[] x = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
Arrays.sort(x);
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(x));

List listObject = Arrays.asList(array)

for(int el : x) {
    System.out.print(listObject.indexOf(el)
}
```

This is assuming your elements in the array are unique. If the elements in your array are of a different type, you should change the type of `x` and `el` accordingly.

Comment: @Lino Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int array[] = {17, 10, 8, 13, 5, 7, 8, 30};

// Init the element list
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    elements.add(new Element(i, array[i]));
}

// Sort and print
Collections.sort(elements);
Collections.reverse(elements); // If you want reverse order
for (Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.value + " " + element.index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an array of indices instead of the array containing the actual data:

```
    Integer[] indices = new Integer[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        indices[i] = i;
    }
    Arrays.sort(indices, (a, b) -> {
        return array[a] < array[b] ? 1 : array[a] > array[b] ? -1 : 0;});
```

Comment: note however that in this example, the indices are zero-based.

Comment: also note that it will be in reverse order: `+1` is returned when `array[a] < array[b]` whereas `-1` is return when `array[a] > array[b]`.

Comment: `array` needs to be `final` in this case. One suggestion is you can just `return Integer.compare(array[a], array[b]);`

Comment: @PhamTrung It depends on the version of Java you're using, but at least, the variable `array` must not be modified.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if you can use lambda in your solution, which mean you can use `Integer.compare`.

Comment: @PhamTrung you may be right, but the type of the elements of the array is not specified in the question.